# How can i interrupt a goroutine executing (*TCPListener) Accept?

Tags: go

I am playing with go lately and trying to make some server which responds to clients on a tcp connection.

My question is how do i cleanly shutdown the server and interrupt the go-routine which is currently "blocked" in the following call

> func (*TCPListener) Accept?

According to the [documentation of Accept](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPListener.Accept)

> Accept implements the Accept method in the Listener interface; it waits for the next call and returns a generic Conn.

The errors are also very scarcely documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i was looking for. Maybe helps someone in the future. 
Notice the use of select and the "c" channel to combine it with the exit channel

```
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    for {
        type accepted struct {
            conn net.Conn
            err  error
        }
        c := make(chan accepted, 1)
        go func() {
            conn, err := ln.Accept()
            c <- accepted{conn, err}
        }()
        select {
        case a := <-c:
            if a.err != nil {
                // handle error
                continue
            }
            go handleConnection(a.conn)
        case e := <-ev:
            // handle event
            return
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe this can leak goroutines because there is nothing which guarantees the channel `c` will be drained. If it gets full because the loop terminates, remaining sends will never complete.

Answer (score 5):

Simply `Close()` the [`net.Listener`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener) you get from the `net.Listen(...)` call and return from the executing goroutine.

Comment: Ok but then how do i identify that the accept failed because of my close without creating some application specific code? According to documentation of http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error that is not easy to grasp. Ok maybe should not matter than much but would be more encapsulated flow if i could know that the socket closed.

Comment: Accept returns two values: the Conn and an error. If the error is not nil then something failed.

Comment: That i know. But how do you know Accept did not fail for some other reason and i just need to retry? Documentation does not say that it will fail only if i close the socket. Also look at the documentation of posix accept. http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept. See how many errors are defined there.

Comment: Check the error's type to be e.g. `net.OpError` or some other error type defined in the `net` package. `_, ok := err.(net.OpError)` would make `ok` either `true` or `false` depending on if `err` is, in fact, of type `net.OpError`

Answer (score 5):

## TCPListener Deadline

You don't necessarily need an extra go routine (that keeps accepting), simply specify a `Deadline`.

`for` example:

```
for {

    // Check if someone wants to interrupt accepting
    select {
    case <- someoneWantsToEndMe: 
        return // runs into "defer listener.Close()"
    default: // nothing to do
    }

    // Accept with Deadline
    listener.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(1 * time.Second)
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Could do some err checking (to be sure it is a timeout), but for brevity
        continue
    }

    go handleConnection(conn)
}
```

Comment: The net.Listener interface does not define a SetDeadline method, you're mixing this up with the net.Conn interface. To stop listener.Accept() from waiting you simply call listener.Close() from another goroutine.

Comment: @ftl: Also a possibility, but also possible as shown above (and btw (imho) quite elegant/simple/clear). OP asked about the TCPListener, consider the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPListener.SetDeadline

Comment: This is the better approach IMHO.