# Setting timeout via SetDeadline() for TCP listener

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement non-blocking `Accept()` and the best I've come so far is the following code snippet (it's a working Go v1.6.2 program):

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func createClient() {
    tcpConn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp4", nil, &net.TCPAddr{
        IP:     net.IPv4(127, 0, 0, 1),
        Port:   12819,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error connecting to the server!")
    }
    log.Println("Managed to dial!")
    tcpConn.Close()
}

func main() {
    go createClient()
    l, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp4", &net.TCPAddr{
        IP:     net.IPv4(127, 0, 0, 1),
        Port:   12819,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Can't listen on provided IP/port!")
    }
    defer l.Close()
    if err = l.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Nanosecond)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Can't set appropriate deadline!")
    }
    tcpConn, err := l.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {
        if opError, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok && opError.Timeout() {
            log.Fatalln("Timeout error!")
        }
        log.Fatalln("Error while accepting connection!")
    }
    log.Println("Accepted new connection!")
    tcpConn.Close()
}
```

The problem is that I always get `Timeout error!`. As far as I understand that's because by the time listener's `AcceptTCP()` gets called the deadline previously set will have already expired. Try changing it to `time.Microsecond` and you'd probably get the same result (unless you have CPU slower than mine). Things start to change only when the deadline gets at least `time.Second`. That's when I start to get `Accepted new connection!`/`Managed to dial!`.

So I think I nailed the problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to use `select` use `syscall.Select`, but that is almost always the wrong way to do it in Go

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825207/how-can-i-interrupt-a-goroutine-executing-tcplistener-accept/48661619#48661619 (An example implementation of `SetDeadline` for a `TCPListener` also there)

Answer (score -1):

Accept is supposed to be blocking. You do not want to set deadline on listen / Accept, as you want it to permanently listen to new connections.

You need to put the accept inside a loop and basically start a new go routine to process the connexion and return to waiting to new client connexion (Accept).

Here is a typical server in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:12819")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Can't listen on provided IP/port!")
    }
    defer l.Close()

    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    if _, err := conn.Read(buf); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
    }
    conn.Write([]byte("Message received."))
    conn.Close()
}
```

You can connect with it with the following command from your shell:

```
telnet localhost 12819
```

Type a command and your request will be handled and processed.

As you see, the accept command is intended to be blocking on purpose. SetDeadline on server is generally used further done in the processing phase to timeout on read on data coming from client.

Comment: Your second statement contradicts with a mere existence of `SetDeadline()` call on `TCPListener` type.

Comment: Nope. The fact that setDeadline exist does not mean you need to use it in general case to make a server. You are using it wrong. I added an example with a typical basic Go server code.

Comment: How do you gracefully shutdown this server if the Accept() call is blocking?

Comment: signals or message via tcp.