# Test TCP connection timeout - net.Listener.Accept() hangs

Tags: unit-testing, go, tcp

I'm trying to test a function that tries to establish a TCP connection.

I'm trying to run a test case that should return an error indicating that a certain IP is not reachable.

The code fails if I wait for a certain amount of time, bigger than the timeout specified, or if I try to connect to a port that wouldn't be available.

The failure seems to be in `l.Accept()` in the tests. The code does not run after that.

The code:

```golang
func Run(
    trackerInfo tracker.NotCompactGetRequestResponse,
    infoHash [20]byte,
) (err error) {
    for _, peer := range trackerInfo.Peers {
        conn, err := peerTcpConnection(peer.Ip, peer.Port)
        if err != nil {
            return PeerConnectionError{
                Reason: err.Error(),
            }
        }
        defer conn.Close()

        handshake := Handshake{
            Pstr:     "BitTorrent protocol",
            InfoHash: infoHash,
            PeerId:   [20]byte(tracker.GetPeerIdAsByteArray()),
        }

        serializedHandshake, err := handshake.Serialize()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, err = conn.Write(serializedHandshake)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func peerTcpConnection(url, port string) (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    address := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", url, port)

    return net.DialTimeout("tcp", address, peerTimeout) // 3 * time.Second
}
```

The test:

```golang
func TestRun(t *testing.T) {
    // t.Parallel()

    testCases := getTestCases()

    for _, testCase := range testCases {
        testCase := testCase

        t.Run(testCase.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            // t.Parallel()

            errChannel := make(chan error)
            go func() {
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("1 -> %v", time.Now()))
                errChannel <- download.Run(testCase.trackerInfo, testCase.infoHash)
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("2 -> %v", time.Now()))
            }()

            l, conn := getTestConnection(t, testCase.trackerInfo.Peers[0].Port)

            defer func() {
                err := conn.Close()
                if err != nil {
                    t.Fatal(err)
                }

                err = l.Close()
                if err != nil {
                    t.Fatal(err)
                }
            }()

            err := <-errChannel

            if !errors.Is(err, testCase.expectedErr) {
                t.Errorf(
                    "got error '%v', expected error '%v'",
                    err,
                    testCase.expectedErr,
                )
            }

            var buffer []byte

            buffer, err = ioutil.ReadAll(conn)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
            }

            receivedHandshake := download.Handshake{}
            receivedHandshake.Deserialize(buffer)

            if !download.CompareHandshakes(receivedHandshake, testCase.expectedHandshake) {
                t.Errorf(
                    "got handshake '%v', expected handshake '%v'",
                    err,
                    testCase.expectedHandshake,
                )
            }
        })
    }
}

func getTestConnection(t *testing.T, port string) (l net.Listener, conn net.Conn) {
    if port == "34568" {
        // portN, err := strconv.Atoi(port)
        // if err != nil {
        //  t.Fatal(err)
        // }

        // port = fmt.Sprint(portN + 1)
        time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    }

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%v", port))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("3 -> %v", time.Now()))
    conn, err = l.Accept()
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("4 -> %v", time.Now()))
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    return l, conn
}
```

The result:

```sh
=== RUN   TestRun
=== RUN   TestRun/successful_download
1 -> 2022-03-16 15:31:04.542987703 +0000 UTC m=+0.000510682
3 -> 2022-03-16 15:31:04.543043416 +0000 UTC m=+0.000566399
4 -> 2022-03-16 15:31:04.543208564 +0000 UTC m=+0.000731539
2 -> 2022-03-16 15:31:04.543257141 +0000 UTC m=+0.000780117
=== RUN   TestRun/unsuccessful_download_-_cannot_connect_to_peer
1 -> 2022-03-16 15:31:04.543331399 +0000 UTC m=+0.000854375
3 -> 2022-03-16 15:31:08.543806112 +0000 UTC m=+4.001329160
```

Comment: The failure is unlikely to be in `Accept()` considering how widely-used it is. [Accept waits for and returns the next connection to the listener](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Listener), so if it's hanging, that means nothing is connecting to it.

Comment: Indeed, that's true. Is there a way of calling `Accept()` and fail this call, instead of hanging, if nothing is trying to connect to it?

Comment: You can set a Deadline or close the listener (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825207/how-can-i-interrupt-a-goroutine-executing-tcplistener-accept))